# sad to relate (meaning)

Tags: comprehension

I don't quite understand what exactly is meant by *sad to relate* as it's used in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: If you know what "relate" means and what "sad" means, what is it you're finding puzzling here?  Consider that "it is" is omitted before that phrase.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Well is it an adjunct describing the subject?

Comment: I don't think it's an adjunct.  It looks like an adverbial phrase, similar to "Unfortunately," or "Interesting to note," -- conveys the feeling of the speaker rather than the situation by itself.

Comment: @VictorBazarov "Adjunct" is modern H&P speak for the term "adverbial"

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  Still, the point is that it does not relate to any part of the sentence, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *sad to relate* is being used as a parenthetical phrase meaning *sadly*. It is easy to understand why this phrase is difficult. The head word here is the adjective *sad*. Because of this, the phrase looks like an Adjunct which might describe the Subject of the main clause:

- Sad to relate the news, Bob told them that they had not passed the exam.

In the sentence above *sad to relate the news* describes Bob, the Subject of the main clause.

However, this cannot make sense in the Original Poster's example:

- Sad to relate, this was a case of XYZ.

Here the word *this* means the previous example. The example cannot be sad, and it isn't relating anything to anyone. The sentence means something like:

- Sadly, this was a case of XYZ.

Comment: re·late /rəˈlāt/
verb 
1. give an account of (a sequence of events); narrate.
Therefore, "sad to relate" = "(it is)sorrow-inducing to tell(you about this)"

Comment: @VictorBazarov Sorry old bean, don't know what you're angling at?

Answer (score 2):

The verb "narrate" means to give an account of, narrate, or tell.
We often hear the idiom "sad to say" that means I regret telling you.
I think "sad to relate" means the same, but it's a bit formal.